# Unable to query a database using spring jpa and apache camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, apache-camel, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to access an oracle sql database using spring jpa since it's a remote server, and apache camel.
This is a code sample:
**RouteBuilder**

```
rest("/getfromdb")
        .get()
        .to("direct:getfromdb");
        
        from("direct:getfromdb")
        .transform().simple("SELECT PERSON_ID FROM XXISF_LEAVE_TEMP;")
        .to("jdbc:dataSource") //spring boot starter jdbc creates the bean in the registry
        .log("${body}");
```

**application.properties file**

```
server.port=9085
camel.servlet.mapping.context-path=/*
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port/serviceName
spring.datasource.username=apps
spring.datasource.password=OneTeam2020
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

**pom, dependencies related to jdbc and jpa**:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
<version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jdbc-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${camel.version}</version>
  <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>            
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>           
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>         
        </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
<artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that my oracle database is 19c, and I am getting the following errors:

```
1- java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
2- org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
3- nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
```

So any idea how to solve this issue? because I did not find anything that could help. Thank you

Comment: I changed the application.properties file: ```server.port=9085
camel.servlet.mapping.context-path=/*
customerKey = admin
customerSecret = OneTeam2020
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1531/hrmsdb
spring.datasource.username=apps
spring.datasource.password=OneTeam2020
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always``` so the errors are solved except ```numeric oveflow``` error

Comment: Where do you get the numeric overflow? How does the table look like and which column is it?